# I got an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error on my Dictionary with enum key in Xcode 6 beta5

Tags: dictionary, enums, swift, xcode6

I have this in my code:

```
enum Direction {
    case up
    case down
    case left
    case right
}
```

...

```
let directions: [Direction: CGVector] = [
        Direction.up: CGVectorMake(0.0, SquareSize.height),
        Direction.down: CGVectorMake(0.0, -SquareSize.height),
        Direction.right: CGVectorMake(SquareSize.width, 0.0),
        Direction.left: CGVectorMake(-SquareSize.width, 0.0)
    ]
```

I get an `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` on my dictionary in Xcode 6 beta5. It worked flawlessly in beta4. What do I need to change so that it work in beta5?

Maybe this can help someone:

> - thread #1: tid = 0x2962f, 0x0002c210 Squares`specialization  of Swift._NativeDictionaryStorage.fromArray (Swift._NativeDictionaryStorage.Type)(Swift.Array<(A, B)>) -> Swift._NativeDictionaryStorage
>     [inlined] specialization <(Squares.Direction, C.CGVector)> of
>     Swift._ArrayBuffer.count.getter : Swift.Int at Square.swift:0, queue =
>     'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
>     (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tried in playground, and it doesn't give any error.

Comment: If I use String key then it's working.
I think this must be a bug in beta5.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you can get that error if any of your variables are `nil`. Try to check this first.

If debugger stop your code at line carefully check it, where any of variables it point are `nil`. Hope it helps.

Comment: There can't be nil in this piece of code, the key is my enum, and the value is a CGVector. Checked SquareSize it's not nil. Besides, the same worked in beta4 without any error.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code on XCode Beta 6 and faced the same issue as you when building in the Release mode. The code build fine in the Debug mode, and that is probably why it passes in the playground.

The problem seems to be with the optimized code that the compiler tries to generate in the Release mode. If you disable optimized code generation, then the code will compile and run just fine.

You can disable optimizations by going to **Build Settings > Swift Compiler - Code Generation**, and setting the **Optimization Level** setting to **'None [-Onone]'** from 'Fastest [-O]'.

You should also [report this bug](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) so Apple can fix it in future releases.